# get all combinations of directories appliable to a device

Tags: android, android-layout

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources it's possible to add alternative resources creating directories whose names are obtained combining the resource name and one or more qualifier.
for example, is possible to specify different contents for portrait and landscape version of the same layout.

I'm having problems, unfortunately, to apply a particular layout to a "specific" device: is there a way to "ask" the app what resources directories is it using?

Alternatively: is there a way to programmatically "list" all the directories a device will search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResources().getConfiguration()` will return a [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) object containing every parameter that will be used for matching resources. Most fields are integers; possible values are also defined on the `Configuration` class. For example, the `orientation` field may be set to `Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` or `Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`.